# Setting up IP addresses in Linux networking

Tags: linux, ip, address, nat

I am running Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server editions on two separate VMs.

For the desktop I have set network adapters:

1. Adapter 1: internal network called intnet
2. Adapter 2: NAT

Server adapters:

1. Adapter 1: internal network called intnet

Now I'm suppose to set ip addresses which I'm pretty sure you do by editing the /etc/network/interfaces file but I'm new to this I don't really get it.

**Ubuntu Desktop**:

static IP 192.168.10.100 for the internal network adapter

netmask 255.255.255.0

dhcp IP for the NAT adapter

**Ubuntu Server**:

static IP 192.168.10.101

netmask 255.255.255.0

^ This is what I need to have set.. how do I do this? I've tried a few things and reset the network and it didn't work. Please can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up IP addresses in Linux networking](http://serverfault.com/questions/211142/setting-up-ip-addresses-in-linux-networking)

Comment: I've already merged the questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.100.100
        gateway 192.168.100.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Don't put the gateway line on the server with the Internet connection.  Its 192.168.100 address should be the gateway address for the other hosts.  See `man interfaces` for information on the interfaces file.

Answer (score 1):

The NAT adapter could be either eth0 or eth1 depending on which one it is connected to.   Run `tail -f /var/log/messages` and remove the cable for either network.  Wait a few seconds and reconnect.  You will get a log message about the connection going up identifying which interface is which.  I try to have eth0 the network (NAT) connection.

I would suggest you install Shorewall and start with the two-interface configuration found in `/usr/share/doc/shorewall/examples/two-interface`.

Your network info for the NAT connection will likely be:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you have a static IP it should be the same as the other interface with the appropriate ip address and net mask.  It should also be the only interface with a gateway line.  See `man interfaces` for detail on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration that I usually use for ubuntu servers (`/etc/network/interfaces`).

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.10.100
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.10.254
```

For a DHCP-assigned interface, you can replace the line starting with iface with:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Don't forget to set your IPs and gateway properly in the example shown above. Also you need to restart the networking service.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the NAT adapter on the desktop? If I run ifconfig it says I have eth0 and eth1 which one would be my NAT adapter and how do I set that? Thanks for the help.